# Why C# Attribute using params doesn't work with my class but work with strings?

Tags: c#, data-annotations

I have an attribute that I'm using `params` in the constructor and I want to pass a class to it in the params.

```
public class FooAttribute: SomeAttribute
{
    public FooAttribute(params Foo[] foo)
    {
        // some code
    }
}

public abstract class Foo
{
    public Foo(int @int, string name)
    {
        // code
    }

    // more code     
}
```

And this doesn't work, when using the attribute

```
[AuthorizeFeature(FooHelper.X, FooHelper.Y)]
```

(`FooHelper` is a static class that instantiate `Foo` with specific constructor parameters)

I get the following error

> Error CS0181  Attribute constructor parameter 'foo' has type 'Foo[]', which is not a valid attribute parameter type

But why it doesn't work? While testing, I changed the type `Foo` for `string` and it work, so I should be able to pass a class with no problems right?

Or maybe I can't pass a abstract class? Or can't pass a class with parameters in the constructor? Or is there something else that is causing this error? I can't figure it out...

Comment: attribute constructor can accept only primitive types which are resolvable at compilation time - strings, numbers, booleans

Comment: Any parameter to an attribute has to be a compile time constant. This generally means only using basic value types. Since these parameters get baked into the binary there are limitations on how complicated they let these operations be. Consider making FooHelper an enumeration value or something like that?

Comment: see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/attributes#attribute-parameter-types)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameters to an `Attribute` constructor must be constants, or Types, or 1-D Arrays of them.

You can't use anything that's merely static readonly. So you're mostly limited to `string`, number literals and constants, `enums` and `Type`. You can't even use `Decimal`.

A workaround is for the parameters to your  Attribute constructor to be the parameters you can use in your Attribute constructor's code to create its own instance.

NB another common gotcha with `Attributes` is that they sometimes turn out to be singletons-per-set-of-parameters. You get little control of `Attributes`.

> An expression E is an attribute_argument_expression if all of the following statements are true:
>
> - The type of E is an attribute parameter type.
> - At compile-time, the value of E can be resolved to one of the following:
>
>   - A constant value.
>   - A System.Type object.
>   - A one-dimensional array of attribute_argument_expressions.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/attributes

and

> The types of positional and named parameters for an attribute class are limited to the attribute parameter types, which are:
>
> - One of the following types: bool, byte, char, double, float, int, long, sbyte, short, string, uint, ulong, ushort.
> - The type object.
> - The type System.Type.
> - An enum type, provided it has public accessibility and the types in which it is nested (if any) also have public accessibility (Attribute specification).
> - Single-dimensional arrays of the above types.
>   A constructor argument or public field which does not have one of these types, cannot be used as a positional or named parameter in an attribute specification.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/attributes#attribute-parameter-types